# How can I deny only one string from a regex pattern

Tags: regex, hex, regex-negation, color-picker

I'm using a regex pattern for Hexadecimal colors validation and been testing it on https://regex101.com .

The problem is that I don't want white - *#FFFFFF* to be considered a valid selection.

I tried this:

> ^#(?=[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})((?!FFFFFF).)*$

and #FFFFFF isn't considered valid as I wanted but now I get

> #FFFasdfsdfg

or this

> #F00

as a valid hexadecimal color, something that with the following pattern doesn't happen:

> ^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want [`^#(?!F+$)(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$`](https://regex101.com/r/OuImks/1)? To match all `#` + 3 or 6 hex chars not equal to just `F`s? To only disallow `#FFFFFF` [use `(?!F{6}$)` lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/OuImks/2).

Comment: Please explain what you want to match and what you want to avoid matching more clearly. Else, we cannot help you.

Comment: I only want to accept all hexadecimal colors format except #FFFFFF

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew +1 it worked! Can't vote your answer, don't know why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^#(?!F{6}$)(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OuImks/2)

The `(?!F{6}$)` negative lookahead fails the match when there are 6 `F` chars right from the first `#` to the end of the string.

If you just want to disallow any number (1 or more) after `#`, [replace `(?!F{6}$)` with `(?!F+$)`](https://regex101.com/r/OuImks/1).